# Delay Between Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my code snippet.

```
    function customFadeIn () {
    $("img.imgKit").each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(1000*index).fadeIn("slow");
    });
    console.log("one runs");
}

function customFadeOut () {
    $("img.imgKit").each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(1000*index).not(document.getElementById('card-6')).fadeOut("slow" , function () {
            $("#card-6").delay(1000).rotate({angle:0});
        });
    });
    console.log("two runs");
}
```

I want the customFadeOut runs only after customFadeIn is done, therefore I call it by this

```
customFadeIn();
customFadeOut();
```

But it did not work, I think I did something wrong here, a help would be really helpful.

Comment: A [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces the problem goes a long way to getting our help, it shows, at least, that you're willing to help us to help you =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make usage of jQuerys `Deferred` / `promise` objects. Animations do also "inherit" those objects and you can apply `jQuery.when()` to shoot for multiple promises to finish.

There are several ways to re-structure your code for that, a simple implementation of this could look like:

```
(function() {
    var promises = [ ];

    function customFadeIn () {
        $("img.imgKit").each(function(index) {
             promises.push( $(this).delay(1000*index).fadeIn("slow").promise() );
        });
    }

    function customFadeOut () {
        jQuery.when.apply( null, promises ).done(function() {
            $("img.imgKit").each(function(index) {
                $(this).delay(1000*index).not(document.getElementById('card-6')).fadeOut("slow" , function () {
                    $("#card-6").delay(1000).rotate({angle:0});
                });
            });
            console.log("two runs");
        });
    }
}());
```

If I did everything correct there, `customFadeOut` sets up a listener which waits for all *animations* / *promises* to finish, before it runs its own code. You don't even have to explicitly call the `.promise()` method at the end, jQuery applies some white magic to link that node with a promise internally for you.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/RGgr3/

---

Looks like I did everything correct ;)

Comment: If I want this code 

    $("#card-6").delay(1000).rotate({angle:0}); 

To be executed only after the customFadeOut ends, where should I put it?